# Whats is return by getChildAt of Fragment Pager Adapter?

Tags: android

My FragmentPagerAdapter is some ListFragment.

when scrolled Page,call  onPageSelected, I want run someMethod in ListFragment.

but problem is  when I ill get Fragment,I tried this

```
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                  ((MyListFragment)((Viewpager)viewPagerAdapter.getChildAt(position))).someMethod;
            }
```

but got error ,viewPager cant cast MyListFragment.

how I get ListFragement?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    ((MyListFragment)viewPagerAdapter.getItem(position)).someMethod();
}
```